# Solving natural log equation for variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I am very confused on how to solve this equation for $k$; I've tried using $ln(x)$, but my math isn't coming out; how can this be solved?

$$3\gamma e^{\gamma k-15000}=-2(1-\gamma)e^{-15000-2k(1-\gamma)}$$

Comment: Taking a log of both sides yields a linear equation. Why did you have trouble solving it?

Comment: Would it then come out to $3\gamma$$(\gamma)k-15000$$=$$-2(1-\gamma)$$-15000-2k(1-\gamma)$?

Comment: No. $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$. The correct expression will have several additive log factors in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct expression after applying $\log$ is the following:

$$\log(3)+\log(\gamma)+[\gamma k-15000]=\log(2)+ \log(\gamma -1) + [-15000-2k(1-\gamma)]$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$3\gamma e^{\gamma k-15000}=-2(1-\gamma)e^{-15000-2k(1-\gamma)} \Rightarrow$$
$$e^{\gamma k-15000+15000+2k(1-\gamma)}=\frac{2(\gamma-1)}{3\gamma} \Rightarrow$$
$$e^{2k-k\gamma}=\frac{2(\gamma-1)}{3\gamma} \stackrel{\ln}\Rightarrow$$
$$2k-k\gamma=\ln{\frac{2(\gamma-1)}{3\gamma}}$$
$$k=\frac{1}{2-\gamma}\cdot \ln{\frac{2(\gamma-1)}{3\gamma}}.$$